# Is there any script/tool to measure tps from apache access log file?

Tags: linux, apache

Most tools that I found measure traffic or other user statistics based on Apache access log files. Is there a script or tool to measure the tps (transactions per second) or hps (hits per second) based on this file. Measuring the same per minute is acceptable.

Thanks,
Alin

Comment: Can you specify if you mean the average or peak tps?

Comment: Both. I managed to accomplish this by using a custom Ruby script.

Answer (score 0):

Try awstats, I have used it in the past and its quite useful. I cannot recall whether it displays tps out of the box, but it can be customized to suit your requirements.